# Solid App Router element not rendering component - Object Object

Tags: solid-js

Just started using SolidJS and solid router, already stuck at the route not rendering the component inside "element". Instead it's showing "[object Object][object Object]"

[image]

See:
https://codesandbox.io/s/solidjs-shopping-cart-wj5zvr?file=/src/App.jsx

Below is the code:

```
import { Router, Route } from "solid-app-router";

function Home() {
  return <h1>Home page here...</h1>;
}
function Cart() {
  return <h1>Cart page here...</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <header>header...</header>
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
      </Router>
      <footer>footer..</footer>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try going with `<Route path="/" component={Home} />` instead.

That also makes it wasy to convert to lazy routes (for code splitting) in the future...

`<Route path="/" component={lazy(() => import("./home"))} />`

EDIT: I took a look at your codesandbox and noticed there is already `<Router>` in `index.jsx` so what you want in `App.jsx` is actually `<Routes>...<Routes>`.

```js
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
      </Routes>
```

Comment: That's what it was @Brendan!. I had to switch it to "Routes". It was staring at my face the whole time. Thank you.